# semigroup actions of groups on regular rooted trees

Tags: gr.group-theory, semigroups-and-monoids

If $G$ is a group which has a semigroup action on a regular rooted tree via prefix-preserving, continuous transformations (I give the tree the path metric), what kinds of algebraic restrictions can we put on $G$?  I have seen a proof, for example, that any such group has decidable word problem, but do these groups need to be residually finite, for example?  Thanks!

Comment: Dan, can you define precisely what you mean by prefix preserving?  Do you mean if f is the map and w=uv is a word, then f(uv)=f(u)x for some word x?

Comment: I would also like to know what a semigroup action of a group is. The identity does not act as an identity?

Comment: @ Mark: I just mean that the identity does not need to pointwise fix the tree.  The identity just needs to be an idempotent e such that eg=ge=g for all g.

Comment: @Ben: sorry for the lack of clarification.  Yeah, I mean what you say above.

Comment: Then I would suggest first to look how an idempotent (1-element semigroup) can act on a tree preserving prefixes. If you know how the identity element acts you should be able to find out everything else. 

Comment: The group will act on the fixed point set of the identity, which will be a tree (since if f fixes a word it must fix all prefixes). The point is that it may no longer be a regular tree. I think groups with a semigroup action on a regular rooted tree (with finite branching) are the same as groups with an action on a rooted tree with bounded branching.  If the tree has max degree d, then choose a retraction from the d-regular tree to your tree for the identity and define the action of all other elements to agree with this retraction off your tree and do what they are supposed to on your tree.

Comment: @Ben: So do groups acting via (root-fixing) homeomorphisms on a rooted tree have algebraic restrictions like residual finiteness?

Comment: @dan: A finitely generated group is residually finite if and only if it acts faithfully on a locally finite rooted tree. Hint: consider the tree of cosets of subgroups of finite index with the root - the group itself. 

Comment: @ Mark.  Thanks Mark!  I can't believe I forgot that characterization of residual finiteness for finitely generated groups.

Comment: I think the problem is still not well posed.  Do you want the action to be by endomorphisms of the tree as a graph, or do you just require the above prefix preserving property above?  The latter can increase length and so is not a graph morphism. 

Comment: @ Ben: I just require the prefix-preserving property, so the functions won't necessarily be graph morphisms.

Comment: @Ben: So I guess I could ask my question in the following way: Are there algebraic restrictions (residual finiteness?) on groups that act as root-fixing homeomorphisms of a rooted tree, where the tree has the path metric?  

Comment: I think in this case you can lose residual finiteness.